# How to create Search Functionality using Optional Parameter in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to build a search functionality in my application. There are many parameters which can be optional.

Model

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "inventoryInspectionReport")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity()
public class Inventory {
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "car_inventory_sequence",
            sequenceName = "car_inventory_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "car_inventory_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String owner;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String km_driven;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer price;
    @Column
    private String fuelType;
    @Column
    private String location;
    @Column
    private String insuranceValidity;
    @Column
    private String rto;
}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/buy-car")
    public String showBuyCarPageList(Model model,
                                     @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page,
                                     @RequestParam("size") Optional<Integer> size
    ){
        int currentPage = page.orElse(1);
        int pageSize = size.orElse(16);
        Page<Inventory> pageObj = carInventoryService.listAllCarIfShow(currentPage, pageSize);
        int totalPages = pageObj.getTotalPages();
        long totalItems = pageObj.getTotalElements();
        List<Inventory> carInventoryList = pageObj.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", 1);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", totalPages);
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", totalItems);
        model.addAttribute("carInfo", carInventoryList);

        return "frontend/buy-car-list";
    }
```

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InventoryServiceImpl implements InventoryService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    InventoryRepository carInventoryRepository;
    InventoryImagesRepository carInventoryImagesRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<Inventory> listAllCarIfShow(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber - 1, pageSize);
        return carInventoryRepository.findAllByShow(true, pageable);
    }
}
```

My question is, how i can create a search functionality? There can be some parameter null? How i can query or ignore the parameters?

Bellow is query samples

```
http://localhost:8080/buy-car?page=1&size=1&name=Car2
http://localhost:8080/buy-car?page=1&size=1&name=Car2&owner=1st
http://localhost:8080/buy-car?page=1&size=1&fuelType=Petrol&owner=1st
```

Sample form image
[image]

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using JPA. You can handle it by writing a query as below. This will ignore the where condition if the parameter is null.

```
@Repository
public class InventoryRepository extends JPARepository<Inventory, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT i FROM Inventory i WHERE (:name is null or i.name = :name) and (:owner is null or i.owner = :owner)")
    Page<Inventory> findAllByShow (String name, String owner, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**PS**: You need to update your `Controller` and `Service` layers to accept other parameters such as **name, owner** etc..

Comment: How i can do pagination?. if you see there is Pageable variable also

Comment: Page<Inventory> will already have pagination information. If you want, you can read the details from Page object and convert it the way you want

Comment: The repository internally handles `Pageable` object and returns Page<Inventory> as per the pageNo, pageSize, Sorting etc... You just need to pass it to repository. It's out of the box feature by Spring JPA.