# How to implement where condition only if we are passing values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, where-clause

This is what I'm calling and passing from service:

```
List<String> projectOwners = filterComponent.getProjectOwner();
List<String> dataProviderCodes = filterComponent.getDataProvider();

custEnrollmentMgmts = customerEnrollmentManagementRepository.findActiveByPage(getArchiveDate(),
                        completedEnrollmentStatusCodes, projectOwners, dataProviderCodes, getNoSearchCriteria(projectOwners, dataProviderCodes), pageRequest);
```

This is the query:

```
select distinct a.* 
from cust_enrollment_mgmt a 
inner join cust_enrollment_rel_mgmt r 
on a.cust_enrollment_proj_id=r.cust_enrollment_proj_id 
left join cust_prime p 
on p.cust_prime_id = r.cust_prime_id 
where a.cust_enrollment_proj_id NOT IN 
( 
    select ce.cust_enrollment_proj_id 
    from cust_enrollment_mgmt ce 
    inner join enrollment_status_avt es 
    on ce.enrollment_status_id = es.enrollment_status_id 
    where ce.sys_update_ts < "2022-06-06 00:00:00" 
    and es.enrollment_status_desc in ("Complete", "Inactive")
)
and 
(
    if ((:code) is not null and (:name) is not null , 
        a.data_provider_cd in (:code) and p.cust_prime_nm in (:name),0) 
    or 
    if ((:code) is not null and (:name) is null , a.data_provider_cd in (:code),0) 
    or 
    if ((:code) is null and (:name) is not null , p.cust_prime_nm in (:name),0)
    or 1=:nosearchcriteria
);
```

- If and only if the dataProviderCodes or projectOwners is not empty
  then only it should go to that where condition.
- If I pass dataProviderCodes and pass projectOwners then it should
  fetch only projectOwner data If I'm not passing anything then it has
  to stop ("Complete", "Inactive") and fetch up to that.
- **After that ("Complete", "Inactive") I need to fetch as per this
  condition ☝☝☝.**

**The main thing is that it has to fetch only if data is present for the param we are passing.**

This is working but if I pass more than 1 data It fails because I'm passing a list it may contain 1 or more than 1 or empty. For example: for dataProviderCodes if I pass ["aa","bb"] it fails.

**I need to perform fetching if and only if the values are not null or present.**

The whole implementation is regarding filtering.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72869555/3485316

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Search Functionality using Optional Parameter in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72868495/how-to-create-search-functionality-using-optional-parameter-in-spring-boot)

Comment: No none of this

Comment: Are you writing a native query?

Comment: Yes inside @Query() springboot